# Django raise ValidationError со своей ошибкой

Tags: python, django

Есть форма, в поле `subject` как аргумент передана строка с ошибками (`error_messages`):

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=20, error_messages={'subject': 'Subject cant be named subject'})
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    sender = forms.EmailField()
    cc_myself = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

    def clean_subject(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['subject'] == 'subject':
            raise forms.ValidationError('error message от поля')
        else:
            print('subject is clear')
        return self.cleaned_data['subject']
```

Как в `raise` `forms.ValidationError('СВОЙ ERROR MESAGE ОТ ПОЛЯ')` в аругмент передать error_messages (конкретный) от поля?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    SUBJECT_ERROR_MESSAGE = 'Subject cant be named subject'
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=20, error_messages={'subject': SUBJECT_ERROR_MESSAGE})
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    sender = forms.EmailField()
    cc_myself = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

    def clean_subject(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['subject'] == 'subject':
            raise forms.ValidationError(self.SUBJECT_ERROR_MESSAGE)
        else:
            print('subject is clear')
        return self.cleaned_data['subject']
```